# Debugging a java code which is not configurable in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I am working on a client code which is not configurable in eclipse. it runs on server at a specific port which is mentioned while requesting to open the application. Actually it is an applet application which use web as a starter afterwards a new pop up window opens and all actions  server send the jar files through cim-xml which is executed on client machine.

Is there any way to debug such code?

Comment: eclipse debugger can attach to a remote JVM, however the app can be undebuggable (depends on debugging stuffs in .class and/or source availability).

Comment: I don't think so, you need new channel (port) to do that. Needs UI application.

Comment: See this for some tips http://javarevisited.blogspot.it/2011/02/how-to-setup-remote-debugging-in.html

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that

> 1. the code you want to debug has debug information.
> 2. You can add some jvm arguments to open the debug port.
> 3. Even if the code is not configurable in eclipse you have access to code.

Now please follow the below steps.
pass below jvm arguments to the server/java process which you want to debug.

> -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8888,server=n,suspend=y

Now connect your eclipse to the debugger port at `8888` and the debugger will start. now you can see that the debugger has started.
put a class loading breakpoint for the class you want to debug.
and when the debugger will start attach the source by clicking on "attach source" button. this button will appear when the class would be loading. and point to the folder where you code is kept. basically we need to stop debugger and and attach the source.
because without importing the code in eclipse its difficult to put the breakpoints.

Comment: I put -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8888,server=n,suspend=y   in Runtime Parameter in java control panel and chhose the run->debug configuration in galileo eclipse and choose the port where my code is and selected the debug option but getting the error failed to connect to remote vm.connection refused.